# Swift issue with nil found while unwrapping an Optional value NSDefautlts

Tags: xcode, swift, null, xcode-6.2

Issue with fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

```
let lastupdate = defaults.stringForKey("localdate")
self.lastUpdate.text = "Updated at " + last update! //issues when I use this line
self.lastUpdate.text = lastupdate // If use this line I have no issues.
```

Works if I pre populate the data. But I would like to allow a nil value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

stringForKey returns an optional, so you can use the nil coalescing operator "??" to return an empty string "" in case of nil:

```
let lastupdate = defaults.stringForKey("localdate") ?? ""
```

Comment: I like the one line approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
let lastupdate = defaults.stringForKey("localdate")
self.lastUpdate.text = {
    if let date = lastupdate {
        return "Updated at \(date)"
    }
    return "Not yet updated"
}()
```

Comment: I also like this approach if I need to make something else happen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if let lastupdate = userDefaults.stringForKey("localdate"){
    self.lastUpdate.text = "Updated at " + lastupdate
    } else {
        println("nil value")
        // do what ever u want
    }
```

Comment: Another great response.