# most concise way of unwrapping and casting optional

Tags: swift

I have a bit of code to get a string out of userDefaults:

```
if let userString = (userDefaults.objectForKey("user")) {
    userTextField.stringValue = userString as! String
}
```

First, I have to see if the optional is not `nil`. Then I have to cast it as a string from `AnyObject`.

Is there a better way of doing this? maybe a one liner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your forced cast `as! String` will crash if a default value for the key "user" exists, but
is not a string. Generally, you can combine optional binding (`if let`) with an optional cast (`as?`):

```
if let userString = userDefaults.objectForKey("user") as? String {
    // ... default value for key exists and is a string ...
    userTextField.stringValue = userString
}
```

But actually `NSUserDefaults` has a dedicated method for that purpose:

```
if let userString = userDefaults.stringForKey("user") {
    // ... default value for key exists and is a string ...
    userTextField.stringValue = userString
}
```

*If* you want to assign a default string in the case that
the default does not exist, or is not a string, then use the
nil-coalescing operator `??`, as demonstrated in 
[Swift issue with nil found while unwrapping an Optional value NSDefautlts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051588/swift-issue-with-nil-found-while-unwrapping-an-optional-value-nsdefautlts/29051624#29051624), e.g.:

```
userTextField.stringValue = userDefaults.stringForKey("user") ?? "(Unknown)"
```

Comment: nil-coalescing operator is pretty sweet.
Can even be used with array :) to awesome.
var paths = userDefaults.arrayForKey(Constants.PATHS) ?? [String]()

Answer (score 1):

For the special case `NSUserDefaults` the best – and recommended – way is to use always non-optional values.

First register the key / value pair in `AppDelegate` as soon as possible but at least before using it.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let defaultValues = ["user" : ""]
defaults.registerDefaults(defaultValues)
```

The benefit is you have a reliable default value of an empty string until a new value is saved the first time. In most `String` cases an empty string can be treated as *no value* and can be easily checked with the `.isEmpty` property

Now write just

```
userTextField.stringValue = userDefaults.stringForKey("user")!
```

Without arbitrary manipulation of the defaults property list file the value is guaranteed to be never `nil` and can be safely unwrapped, and when using `stringForKey` there is no need for type casting.

Comment: I really like the safety of this. I think combining it with constants for the key values to prevent misspellings I'll have a winning situation.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, stringForKey("user") can still return nil (e.g. if the user preference has been set to a value with a different type such as an array).

Comment: @MartinR It's tedious enough to have to catch all possible errors the users can cause, do we really need to extend that to the developer's carelessness? ;-)

Comment: Sure, it may not be relevant. But the statement "The value is guaranteed to be never nil" is at least misleading.

Comment: Is that better? @MartinR

Comment: Hmm your code does not work as shown. userTextField.stringValue = userDefaults.stringForKey("user") is saying it's still a optional that must be unwrapped. Even though I've done the registration.

Comment: Sorry, of course you must unwrap the value, but it's safe, I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

> Another way that i like much to clean this up is to do each of your checks 
>   first, and exit if any aren’t met. This allows easy understanding of what
>   conditions will make this function exit.

Swift has a very interesting `guard` statements which can also be used to avoid force unwrap crashes like :

```
guard let userString = userDefaults.objectForKey("user") as? String else {
    // userString var will accessible outside the guard scope
    return
}
    userTextField.stringValue = userString
```

> Using guards you are checking for bad cases early, making your
>   function more readable and easier to maintain. If the condition is not
>   met, guard‘s else statement is run, which breaks out of the function.
>   If the condition passes, the optional variable here is automatically
>   unwrapped for you within the scope that the guard statement was
>   called.